# GAS 'Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation' error present when run from menu, but not present when run from editor

Tags: google-apps-script

A GAS function is triggered from a sheet custom menu. This function is executed daily and has worked without error for weeks. A couple days ago, users started to see the so unhelpful "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation" error. I have found that I can execute the exact same function from the code editor without error, but consistently re-produce the error when using the menu. More odd, everything I expect the function (and others called by it) appears to be completing correct.

How can I trouble-shoot an error and file a problem report with google when I can't run isolate parts of the script to narrow down the problem?

Comment: One way to debug is to introduce Logger.log statements in your code and see where it breaks. The execution transcript might be useful as well. When you've found out where it breaks, if it is unexpected, then file an issue in the Issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your trigger-code inside a try-catch block:

```
function calledByTriggerOrMenu () {
  try {
    doTheThings();
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log ("Catched something: "+e+"\n"+e.stack);
  }
}
```

Then you know exactly where the error occured